# Python3: printing string with special characters

Tags: python

I am trying to get running a very simple python script on Ubuntu using python 3.5 but seeing an error. The same example works fine with python2.7

### python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

my_list = ['éléphant', 'Hello World']
print(my_list[0])
print(my_list[1])
```

### Output using python 3.5

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(my_list[0])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

### Output using python 2.7

```
éléphant
Hello World
```

If I change the above code as follows, then python3.5 prints encoded characters as below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

my_list = ['éléphant', 'Hello World']
print(my_list[0].encode("utf-8"))
print(my_list[1])
```

### Output

```
b'\xc3\xa9l\xc3\xa9phant'
Hello World
```

Any thoughts on how to get python3 to print similar output as python2.7?

Comment: works for me python 3.7...try r'string'

Comment: Works on 3.6.1.

Comment: I just tried it on 3.6, and it works the same as you expect. May be try double quotes.

Comment: works well on py3.7, py3.4.3

Comment: Works for me on Python 3.5.1

Comment: `print` uses encoding which it gets from console. You can see this encoding with `print( sys.stdout.encoding )`. If it can't get encoding (console has no set encoding or it runs in script or in piping which doesn't use encoding) then it may have problem to display it correctly. You may have to configure console to get correct result. ie. Polish language with UTF-8 `LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8`

Comment: I cannot replicate this.

Comment: you can also try to use `export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8` in system. You can put this in `~/.bashrc`

Comment: using `export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8`, as [furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas) pointed out, got it working for me. For some reason, py 3.5 was not picking up the encoding as seen in output of `print( sys.stdout.encoding )` but setting above environment variable got it working. Thank you all for the responses.